# View with multiple partial views posting back

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC (MVC3) so not sure about the best way to implement this.

I want to create a single "main" view (not strongly-typed). This "main" view will contain multiple strongly-typed partial views that each contain a form. Each partial view will therefore post back to their own POST action that does whatever. The problem I see is that when a partial view posts back, it needs to only update the partial view itself and not affect the other partial views on the page.

When I postback from a partial view now, it just returns the partial view alone back, rather than the entire "main" page.

How can this functionality be achieved in MVC3? (from a high-level perspective)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post data by AJAX.
In my example I use jQuery:

```
<div id="first-form" class="form-container">
   @Html.Partial("FirstPartial")
</div>

<div id="second-form" class="form-container">
   @Html.Partial("SecondPartial")
</div>

// and here go rest forms
```

Your partial view may be following:

```
@model YourModelClass
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // some fields go there
}
<input type="button" value="Save Form Data" class="save-button"/>
```

Js would be following:

```
$("input.save-button").on("click", function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var container = button.closest("div.form-container");
    var url = container.find("form").attr("action");   

    container.busy($.post(url, function (response) {
       container.html(response);
    }));

    return false;
});
```